# Stack image over full page background in the middle

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
.big-img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.small-img{
  border: 1px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  right: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 25%;
  max-width:25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="big-img" src="https://webhostingvirtualdedicatedservers.com/files/2012/09/Web-server.png" />
  <img class="small-img" src="http://loosechange.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Personal-Discount-10-lg.jpg" />
</div>
```

So, I want to place a logo right in the middle of a background image which is full page size (`height: 100vh`). I can do it in about 10 seconds using Elementor, but I have to do it on a website without any CMS, so that's hard for me. I tried literally any snippet I could find online, but it was always about how to stack an image on top of another image, not an image on top of a full-page background.

Here's an example of what I found: https://jsfiddle.net/uu3pqwpa/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow... Perhaps you have not googled it?https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would literally use a `background-image`in the CSS for the large container and apply flex settings to it (details see below) to center the smaller `img` tag within that `div` (i.e. no absolute/relative positioning, no two  `img` tags):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.big-img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://placehold.it/2000x1500/fda?text=Background-Image') center center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.small-img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
  height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-img">
  <img class="small-img" src="https://placehold.it/200x100/ab7?text=centered-Image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background of the wrapper using

`background: url('https://webhostingvirtualdedicatedservers.com/files/2012/09/Web-server.png);`

keeping it position relative, but adding:

`width: 100%;
height: auto;`

And then leave the small image positioned absolutely

Answer (score 0):

Placing the images as background images will make it possible to use `background-size: cover` and have them fit in any size of the container.

Using pseudo-elements, like `::before`, is just a way of clear up HTML code with elements that are mostly there for styling.

Any other kind of clarification down below in the code as comments.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0px;  /* remove default spacing */
  margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;  /* min lets the element span beyond the page, if necessary. */
  
  /* didn't find image */
  /* background: url('https://webhostingvirtualdedicatedservers.com/files/2012/09/Web-server.png'); */
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
}

.wrapper, .wrapper::before {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* needed to include border size in width and height */
  border: 1px solid blue;

  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw; /* make it squarish */
  
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  /* move element negative 50% of it's own size on both x and y coordinate */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  border-color: red;
  /* background: url('http://loosechange.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Personal-Discount-10-lg.jpg'); */
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/200/200');
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100vh;
  
}
.big-img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.small-img{
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  width: 25%;
  height:25%;
}

body {
 background-image: url("https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/1c9/maine-at-4-45-am-1370871.jpg"); 
 background-size: cover;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  
  <img class="small-img" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/small-previews/25d/eagle-1523807.jpg"/>
  
  </div>
```